# Webdriver.io pageObject pattern - define element selector by passing argument

Tags: javascript, selenium, webdriver, webdriver-io

I am following the example, in order to define elements within pageObjects, using the ID selector...

```
var Page = require('./page')

var MyPage= Object.create(Page, {
    /**
     * define elements
     */
    firstName: { get: function () { return browser.element('#firstName-0'); } },
    lastName: { get: function () { return browser.element('#lastName-0'); } },

...
```

I am looking a way to pass an argument that would allow me to dynamically define the selector.  e.g. `'#firstName-0'` I would like to have `'#firstName-' + i` so I could collect multiple first names.

I have tried

```
firstName: { get: function (i) { return browser.element('#firstName-' + i);}}
```

then within the test..

```
MyPage.firstName.get(0).setValue('foo');
```

but it complains that `get()` is not a function.

Doe anyone have any ideas?

Comment: could you please try and change the name of the method other than `get` and update.

Comment: sorry, not sure what your getting at?

Comment: I am guessing that there is a conflict in accessing elements of a list (`list.get(index)`) and calling a method here(in your case `get(i)`) and want to ensure its not that you're ending up into.

Comment: ok, it still complains that it is not a function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way to define a function on a property with a property descriptor:

```
var Page = require('./page')

var MyPage= Object.create(Page, {
    /**
     * define elements
     */
    firstName: { value: { get: function (i) { return browser.element('#firstName-' + i); } } },
...
```

Usage:

```
MyPage.firstName.get(0).setValue('foo');
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!  What caught me out is my lack of understanding of the `get` and `value` functions.  Do you know of anywhere that explains what these are and how/when they get called?

Comment: Have a look at MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create